# Android: Get text Editext == item array

Tags: android

I have this code

```
if(edt_i.getText().toString() == Arrays.asList(coupon).contains("VIP537129")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"50% ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

My Array

```
String[] coupon = {
        "MEM537128",
        "MEM537129",
        "VIP537128",
        "VIP537129"
    };
```

I want to check text in Edittext with Array, But didn't working. Please help me!

**EDIT**

```
        if (Arrays.asList(coupon).contains(edt_i.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"10% ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(Arrays.asList(coupon).contains(edt_i.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"20% ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(Arrays.asList(coupon).contains(edt_i.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," 30% ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(Arrays.asList(coupon).contains(edt_i.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"50% ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," False ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

But Toast only show 10%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about your question. is this what u need ?

```
int[] percent = {10,20,30,50};


 if(Arrays.asList(coupon).contains(edt_i.getText().toString())) 
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,percent[Arrays.asList(bigger).indexOf(edt_i.getText().toString())].toString()+"%", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," False ", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This working but i have multi item in list, so i can't use this method

Comment: hmm i dont get what you mean. Do you need to get the index where the string exist in the array ? or ?

Comment: hope it helps @NamJayer

Answer (score 0):

You need to check a String contains in String Array, like this,

```
if(Arrays.asList(coupon).contains(edt_i.getText().toString())) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"50% ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This working but i have multi item in list, so i can't use this method

Answer (score 0):

you must to use method indexOf in order to find position of inputText in coupon array.

```
    String inputText = edt_i.getText().toString();
    switch (Arrays.asList(test).indexOf(inputText)) {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"10% ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"20% ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"30% ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 3:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"50% ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," False ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```